# Si tiene una opcion seleccionada, mostrar input date html js

Tags: javascript, html

Dado el código, como puedo añadir con javascript si se selecciona select option

```
<option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
```

que aparezca

```
<input id="date" type="date">
```

y que desaparezca

```
 <input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>*<br />
```

dado el código:

**convertidor.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- Programa: Convertidor-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Convertidor</title>
    <head>

    <body>
        <h1>Convertidor</h1>

        Mensaje a descifrar
        <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
        <select name="cifrado">
            <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
            <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
            <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
            <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
            <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
            <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
            <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
        </select>   

        </select><br/>
           <!–  Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar ->

            <label for="texto">Numero a convertir</label>
            <!–  filtarado solo valores positivos ->
             <input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>*<br />

            <!–  Borrar los valores ->
            <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>    
            <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

            <!–  Recoger los datos ->
            <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
            <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes agregar un listener a los cambios del `select`, usar una variable (`status`) para verificar si el valor es igual a `dateDecToRoman` y por medio de esa variable ocultar/mostrar cada `input`.

Por ejemplo:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

  /* Referencias a cada elemento */
  var selConverter = document.getElementById("selConverter");
  var ibxDate = document.getElementById("date");
  var ibxNumber = document.getElementById("numero");
  var mForm = document.getElementById("mForm");
  
  /*Listener para los cambios en el select*/
  selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var status = e.target.value === "dateDecToRoman";
    ibxDate.hidden = !status;
    ibxNumber.hidden = status;

  });

  /*Listener para cuando se presione el submit del form*/
  mForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("aquí todo lo que haya que hacer al momento de enviar");
  });
  
});
```

```html
<h1>Convertidor</h1>
<form id="mForm" action="resultado.php" method="post">
  <select name="cifrado" id="selConverter">
    <option value="-1">--Select conversion--</option>
    <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
    <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
    <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
    <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
    <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
    <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
    <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
  </select>

  <br/>
  <!–  Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar ->

  <label for="texto">Numero a convertir</label>
  <!–  filtarado solo valores positivos ->
  <input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" placeholder="number" required />*<br />
  <input id="date" type="date" placeholder="date" hidden />

  <!–  Borrar los valores ->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

  <!–  Recoger los datos ->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

</form>
```

**NOTAS:**

- Tenías un cierre `</select>` de más, debes corregirlo.
- Cuando se oculta el `input number` quizá convenga ocultar su etiqueta. Es un poco incoherente de todos modos ocultar un campo marcado como `required` sin tener al menos un valor predeterminado. Quizá una opción interesante sería tener un solo `input` y modificar sus atributos de forma dinámica según se seleccione o no `dateDecToRoman`

Comment: sin duda excelente, pero si no estoy mal al hacer click en "Date dec To Roman" debe mostrar el input "date"..

Comment: Correcto @DiegoAvila, gracias por la observación, me confundí con el primer valor, ya está corregido.

Comment: pero esta opcion no te deja enviar, no hace nada cuando le das a enviar, gracias por su respuesta

Comment: @kit ¿te refieres a que no deja enviar el formulario? Ahora te pongo el código para ello, pensé que lo tenías controlado...

Comment: gracias :D compañero, ya esta todo

Comment: @kit ahí lo tienes, y de paso le agregué un listener para `DOMContentLoaded`, siempre se recomienda poner todo el código dentro de ese bloque, para asegurar que no se use nada del DOM sin que éste se haya cargado. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por el apoyo! :)

Comment: no sé por que pero ahora, no me envia a resultado.php :S

Comment: @kit sí, perdona, tienes que quitarle esta línea: `e.preventDefault();` es que yo para estas cosas uso ¡Ajax!, de modo que no haga falta refrescar la página y cuando de usa Ajax se le pone eso precisamente para que no se refresque la página.

Comment: gracias por la aclaración :)

Answer (score 3):

Saludos puedes hacerlo con algo de JavaScript:

```js
 //seleccionando elementos
  var inputDate = document.getElementById('date');
  var inputNumero = document.getElementById('numero');
 var select = document.getElementById('cifrado');
  
  //ocultar input fecha y numero
  inputDate.style.display = "none";
  inputNumero.style.display = "none";
  
function mostrarInput(){
 var valorSeleccionado = select.value;
  if(valorSeleccionado == 'dateDecToRoman'){
    //ocultar input numero en caso de estar mostrandolo
      inputNumero.style.display = "none";
     //mostrar input fecha
      inputDate.style.display = "block";
  }else{
    //ocultar input fecha en caso de estar mostrandolo
      inputDate.style.display = "none";
     //mostrar input numero
      inputNumero.style.display = "block";
  }

}// end function mostrarInput
```

```html
<select name="cifrado" id="cifrado" onchange="mostrarInput();">
  <option value="" selected disabled>----------</option>
  <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
  <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
  <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
  <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
  <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
  <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
  <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
</select><br>
<input type="date" name="date" id="date" required>
<input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>
```

si te fijas en el select tengo un evento **onchange** el mismo al seleccionar una **option** invoca a una funcion (mostrarInput) dentro de esta obtengo el valor seleccionado y mediante un **if** valido lo que necesito y muestro el respectivo input sea fecha o numero(date/numero).

Antes de la Función **mostrarInput** lo que hace es seleccionar los elementos por ID y tambien por defecto cargo ocultos los inputs que mostrare segun sea el caso.

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: la parte de js, hay que meterlo en script ?

Comment: si en efecto(<script>...aqui....</scri>) o a su vez puedes usar un archivo externo(archivo.js) e incluirlo en tu pagina html

Answer (score 3):

Si vas a usar jQuery:

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#selector').change(function() {
      if (this.value == 'dateDecToRoman') {
        $('#date').toggle(false);
        $('#numero').toggle(true);
      } else {
        $('#date').toggle(true);
        $('#numero').toggle(false);
      }
    })

    // asignamos la visibilidad inicial
    $('#date').toggle(false);
    $('#numero').toggle(true);

  }); 
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector" name="cifrado">
  <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
  <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
  <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
  <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
  <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
  <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
  <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
</select>
<br>
<!–- Introducimos el texto a cifrar/descrifrar -->

<label for="texto">Dato a convertir</label>
<!-–  filtarado solo valores positivos -->
<input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required>*<br />
<input id="date" type="date">


<!-–  Borrar los valores -->
<label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
<input type="reset" value="Borrar">

<!-–  Recoger los datos -->
<label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
<input type="submit" name="Enviar"
```

Comment: ¿Por qué nos mandas a `jsfiddle`, si los fragmentos de código funcionan de maravilla para este tipo de respuestas?

Comment: La costumbre, al llevar jQuery me resulta más cómodo en jsfiddle y ni me fije que ester editor también permite librerias

Comment: Sí permite librerías externas predefinidas o puestas a mano mediante enlace. Lo único que no funciona son cosas como localstorage, por seguridad, supongo.

Comment: Cambiado, gracias por el apunte, aunque me gusta más como editor el jsfiddle es mejor que el código se quede aquí, así se evitar perderlo.

Answer (score 3):

Como dice @A.cedano, puedes agregar un `listener` para que no agregues las funciones en tu etiqueta HTML, yo le agregue otra función que es la de `setAttribute` ya que si lo colocas fijamente el atributo `required` en tu etiqueta si esta oculto y no tiene ningun `value` te va a mandar un error por consola, así que yo le agrego el atributo `required` con `setAttribute` cuando se muestra y cuando se oculta lo remuevo con `removeAttribute`, tienes muchas opciones de donde elegir, saludos :)

```js
var cifrado = document.getElementById('cifrado');

cifrado.addEventListener('change',function(){

if(this.value == 'dateDecToRoman'){

document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('numero').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('numero').removeAttribute('required','');

}else{
document.getElementById('date').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('numero').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('numero').setAttribute('required','');

}

});
```

```html
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Convertidor</title>


    <head>

    <body>

        <h1>Convertidor</h1>


        Mensaje a descifrar
        <form action="resultado.php" method="post">
        <select name="cifrado" id="cifrado">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Selecciona:</option>

            <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>

            <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>

            <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>

            <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>

            <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>

            <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>

            <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>

        </select>   
        

<input id="date" type="date" style="display: none">

<input id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" style="display: none">
```