# ocultar y mostrar, 3 inputs en diferentes options

Tags: javascript, html

Como puedo hacer que se muestre:

```
  <input name="text" id="text" type="text" hidden>
```

Solo cuando se seleccione romanToDec,romanToHex,hexToRoman

para el input numerico, que solo se muestre decToRoman,decToBin,BinToDec

y para date que solo se muestre con dateDecToRoman

sería así? pero no me funciona:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

    /* Referencias a cada elemento */
    var selConverter = document.getElementById("selConverter");
    var ibxDate = document.getElementById("date");
    var ibxNumber = document.getElementById("numero");
    var ibxText = document.getElementById("text");
    var mForm = document.getElementById("mForm");

       /*Listener para los cambios en el select*/
selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  var status = e.target.value === "dateDecToRoman";
  ibxDate.hidden = !status;
  ibxNumber.hidden = status;
    var status2= e.target.value === "romanToDec"||"romanToHex"||"hexToRoman";
    ibxText.hidden=!status;
    ibxNumber.hidden = status;
});


    selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        var status = e.target.value === "romanToDec"||"romanToHex"||"hexToRoman";
        ibxText.hidden = !status;
        ibxNumber.hidden = status;

      });




  });
```

```js
 

   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

        /* Referencias a cada elemento */
        var selConverter = document.getElementById("selConverter");
        var ibxDate = document.getElementById("date");
        var ibxNumber = document.getElementById("numero");
        var mForm = document.getElementById("mForm");
        
          /*Listener para los cambios en el select*/
    selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
      var status = e.target.value === "dateDecToRoman";
      ibxDate.hidden = !status;
      ibxNumber.hidden = status;
        var status2= e.target.value === "romanToDec"||"romanToHex"||"hexToRoman";
        ibxText.hidden=!status;
        ibxNumber.hidden = status;
    });
  
    
    
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Convertidor</title>
       

    <head>

    <body>

    <h1>Convertidor</h1>
<form id="mForm" action="resultado.php" method="post">
  <select name="opciones" id="selConverter">
    <option  disabled>--Select conversion--</option>
    <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
    <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
    <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
    <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
    <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
    <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
    <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
  </select>

  <br/>


  <label for="texto">Numero a convertir</label>
  <!–  filtarado solo valores positivos ->
  <input name="number" id="numero" type="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" placeholder="number" required />*<br />
  <input name="date"id="date" type="date" placeholder="date" hidden />
  <input name="text" id="text" type="text" hidden>

  <!–  Borrar los valores ->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

  <!–  Recoger los datos ->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

</form>
       
        <script src="funcion.js">
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Tienes que poner toda la lógica dentro de un solo bloque `selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) { /*Aquí toda la lógica*/ });`, al tener dos listeners iguales, sólo entrará en el primero. De todos modos, sería más simple (creo) resolver esto mediante clases en los elementos.

Comment: gracias, no sabia, como lo podría hacer, y por que  no me lo cogía

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Si tiene una opcion seleccionada, mostrar input date html js](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/254992/si-tiene-una-opcion-seleccionada-mostrar-input-date-html-js)

Comment: he intentado ponerlo en el mimso listeners, pero no hayo la solución para esta pregunta

Comment: Te recomiendo que en vez de usar hidden uses display: none;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hidden` es un tipo (`type`) de input. Un elemento `<input>` no puede tener `type="text"` y `type="hidden"` en el mismo momento. Así que en tu HTML he cambiado todos los elementos que quieres esconder a `type="hidden"`y si lo quieres hacer visible cambias el `type` a `text`, `date` o `number` según el caso.

Espero que sea útil.

```js
var selConverter = document.getElementById("selConverter");
        var ibxDate = document.getElementById("date");
        var ibxNumber = document.getElementById("numero");
        var mForm = document.getElementById("mForm");

 selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {  //recupera el valor del elemento option seleccionado
   let val = selConverter.options[selConverter.selectedIndex].value;
   
   if(val == "romanToDec" || 
      val == "romanToHex" ||
      val == "hexToRoman"){
      text.setAttribute("type","text");
      ibxNumber.setAttribute("type","hidden");
      ibxDate.setAttribute("type","hidden");
   }
   
   if(val == "decToRoman" || 
      val == "decToBin" ||
      val == "BinToDec"){
      text.setAttribute("type","hidden");
      ibxNumber.setAttribute("type","number");
      ibxDate.setAttribute("type","hidden");
   }
   
   if(val == "dateDecToRoman"){
      text.setAttribute("type","hidden");
      ibxNumber.setAttribute("type","hidden");
      ibxDate.setAttribute("type","date");
   }
 })
```

```html
<h1>Convertidor</h1>
<form id="mForm" action="resultado.php" method="post">
  <select name="opciones" id="selConverter">
    <option  disabled selected>--Select conversion--</option>
    <option value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
    <option value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
    <option value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
    <option value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
    <option value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
    <option value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
    <option value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
  </select>

  <br/>


  <label for="texto">Numero a convertir</label>
  <!-- filtarado solo valores positivos -->
  <input name="number" id="numero" type="hidden" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" placeholder="number"/>*<br />
  
  
  <input name="date" id="date" placeholder="date" type="hidden" />
  <input name="text" id="text" type="hidden">

  <!-- Borrar los valores -->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

  <!-- Recoger los datos -->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

</form>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, fue muy útil

Comment: Ojo, los `input` inicialmente tienen una propiedad `hidden`, no es que sean del tipo `text` y del tipo `hidden` al mismo tiempo. En cuanto a tu propuesta de definir el tipo a `hidden` para todos los inputs, ten en cuenta que los tipos `hidden` tienen algunas restricciones ( [ver aquí](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#hidden-state-type%3Dhidden) y [ver aquí](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#do-not-apply) ), por lo que se estará produciendo un HTML inicial con errores aunque no afecte el funcionamiento.

Answer (score 2):

Esta solución te podría convenir. Explico brevemente en qué consiste:

- De entrada todos los `input` aparecen ocultos.
- Daremos a cada `option` un atributo de datos `data-type` donde indicaremos si para esa opción se requiere mostrar el input `text`, `number` o `date`.
- En el *listener*, crearemos dos cadenas de query para agrupar mediante `querySelectorAll` por un lado el `input` del tipo que se halla seleccionado y por otro lado los inputs de los otros tipos.
- En base a esas dos query mostraremos el input que corresponda y ocultaremos los que no correspondan. Para hacer esa diferenciación y no estar seleccionando elementos a lo loco, he puesto a los tres `input` la clase `group` y a cada uno de ellos otra clase `number`, `text` o `date`, según el caso.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {

  /* Referencias a cada elemento */
  var selConverter = document.getElementById("selConverter");
  var ibxDate = document.getElementById("date");
  var ibxNumber = document.getElementById("numero");
  var ibxText = document.getElementById("text");

  /*Listener para los cambios en el select*/
  selConverter.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var thisIndex = e.target.selectedIndex;
    var queryHide = "";
    /*Verificamos si no se volvió a la primera opción*/
    if (thisIndex != 0) {
      var mDataSet = e.target.options[thisIndex].dataset;
      /*Para buscar el input con la clase del data-type seleccionado*/
      var queryShow = `input.${mDataSet.type}`;
      /*Para buscar los inputs que no tienen la clase del data-type seleccionado*/
      queryHide = `input.group:not(.${mDataSet.type})`;

      /*El input a mostrar*/
      document.querySelector(queryShow).hidden = false;
    } else {
      /*Cuando se vuelva a la 1ª opción ocultaremos todo*/
      queryHide = `input.group`;
    }
    /*Los inputs a ocultar*/
    document.querySelectorAll(queryHide).forEach(function(e) {
      e.hidden = true;
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<h1>Convertidor</h1>
<form id="mForm" class="converter" action="resultado.php" method="post">
  <select name="opciones" id="selConverter">
    <option data-type="none" default>--Select conversion--</option>
    <option data-type="number" value="decToRoman">Dec To Roman</option>
    <option data-type="text" value="romanToDec">Roman To Dec</option>
    <option data-type="text" value="romanToHex">Roman To Hex</option>
    <option data-type="number" value="hexToRoman">Hex To Roman</option>
    <option data-type="number" value="decToBin">Dec To Bin</option>
    <option data-type="number" value="BinToDec">Bin To Dec</option>
    <option data-type="date" value="dateDecToRoman">Date dec To Roman</option>
  </select>

  <br/> Dato a convertir:<br />
  <!–  filtarado solo valores positivos ->
  <input name="number" id="numero" type="number" class="group number" placeholder="number" min="1" pattern="^[0-9]+" required hidden />*<br />
  <input name="date" id="date" type="date" class="group date" placeholder="date" hidden />
  <input name="text" id="text" type="text" class="group text" placeholder="text" hidden />

  <!–  Borrar los valores ->
  <label for="Borrar">¿Quieres resetear?</label>
  <input type="reset" value="Borrar">

  <!–  Recoger los datos ->
  <label for="Enviar">Enviar</label>
  <input type="submit" name="Enviar">
</form>
```